# GetLegendGraphic display horizontal GeoServer

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I am working on a school project and I am wondering how do I display the legend of the map horizontally I am using GeoServer version 2.13. I have tried the below code and it's not working... help me please!

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=50&HEIGHT=30&LAYER=schoolProjects:GITD_Project&legend_options=layout:horizontal">
```

I have tried with LEGEND_OPTIONS doesn't work.
I have also tried to set number rows and the height and width of columns it doesn't work either.

Comment: What output do you get? Do you get an error? Do you get an empty tile?

Comment: I get the normal vertical legend... As somoene suggested below, I will try to add top:states and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

When I try your URL with the `topp:states` layer I get:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=50&HEIGHT=30&LAYER=topp:states&legend_options=layout:horizontal
```

[image]

Which looks correct to me, so I suspect there is something wrong with your SLD. You might find [GIS Stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) a better place to ask about that.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try to use topp:states  and see if it works!